# Make a treeview scrollable at a custom number of rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

In this treeview, I want to store rows with a rowheight of 500 (for example). As you can see I have attached a scrollbar which allows the Treeview to be scrollable, however the Treeview is not scrollable. I believe this is due to the **treeview requiring a certain amount of rows** before being scrollable, despite if it is impossible to see the next row.

```
# Components for PatrolOverview
POStyle=ttk.Style()
POStyle.configure('POStyle.Treeview', rowheight=500)
PatrolView = ttk.Treeview(PatrolOverview,style='POStyle.Treeview')
PatrolTitleLabel = tk.Label(PatrolOverview, text="Patrol Overview", font=TitleFont, bg="white")
PatrolTitleLabel.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=5)
PatrolView["columns"] = ("image", "patrolname", "patrolleader", "patrolaleader", "score")
PatrolView.grid(row=2, column=1)
PatrolView.heading("patrolname", text="Patrol Name", anchor="w")
PatrolView.column("patrolname", anchor="center", width=70)
PatrolView.heading("patrolleader", text="Patrol Leader", anchor="w")
PatrolView.column("patrolleader", anchor="center", width=70)
PatrolView.heading("patrolaleader", text="Assistant Patrol Leader", anchor="w")
PatrolView.column("patrolaleader", anchor="center", width=70)
PatrolView.heading("score", text="Patrol Score", anchor="w")
PatrolView.column("score", anchor="center", width=70)
PatrolView.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=5)
PatrolViewScrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(PatrolOverview, orient="vertical", command=PatrolView.yview)
PatrolView.configure(yscroll=PatrolViewScrollbar.set)
PatrolViewScrollbar.grid(row=2, column=6, sticky="ns")
```

Since I am using the `.grid` method, I cannot give an accurate pixel measurement of the treeview, so here is a screen cap. 
[image: treeview]

As seen in the image, the treeview only shows one row (should be three) and the scrollbar is not working.

Comment: Add the number of Rows you want to show: `ttk.Treeview(PatrolOverview, height=2`. Note: You are doing `PatrolView.grid(...` twice.

Comment: Sorry I am hard of sight.